# How to use MariaDB's REGEXP_REPLACE?

Tags: mariadb

I have read [the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/) for MariaDB's `REGEX_REPLACE` but cannot get my query to work. I am storing links in a column, `link` and want to change the end of the link:

From `www.example.com/<code>` to `www.example.com/#/results/<code>` where `<code>` is some hexidecimal hash, e.g. `55770abb384c06ee00e0c579`. What I am trying is:

```
SELECT REGEX_REPLACE("link", "www\\.example\\.com\\/(.*)", "www\\.example\\.com\\/#\\/results\\/\\1");
```

The result is:

`Showing rows 0 - 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out what the first argument was--the documentation says "subject". Turns out it's just the column name. So this works:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_link = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    my_link,
    "http:\\/\\/www\\.example\\.com\\/(.*)",
    "http:\\/\\/www\\.example\\.com\\/#\\/results\\/\\1")
WHERE my_link IS NOT NULL
```